# Can I edit choices without affecting the already submitted responses?

Tags: google-forms

So I have made a form for a project. I got some responses, but now I want to translate the whole form into English. The problem is that if I try to edit the choices, the responses stay the same, in the original language. I know this may be a precaution against fake form results, but is there any way to edit the choices and keep the responses linked to that choice?

For example: I have a question with 2 choices, "Da/Nu". I want to change them to "Yes/No", but if I do, the responses remain the same and the only thing that changes is that "Yes" and "No" become new choices with no results associated to them. How can I edit the form so after translating the text, the only 2 options will be "Yes" and "No", with the same results as "Da/Nu" had?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably easiest to do in a [form responses spreadsheet](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2917686?hl=en#zippy=%2Cchoose-where-to-store-responses). If you do not have a form responses spreadsheet, click **More ︙ > Select response destination > Create a new spreadsheet**.

In the form responses spreadsheet, you will see a tab named 'Form Responses 1' or similar. Choose **Insert > New sheet**, and put this formula in cell `A1` of the new sheet:

```
=arrayformala( 
  ifs( 
    'Form Responses 1'!A1:Z = "Da", "Yes", 
    'Form Responses 1'!A1:Z = "Nu", "No", 
    true, 'Form Responses 1'!A1:Z 
  ) 
)
```

The new sheet will update dynamically, and will replace all `Da`s with `Yes`es.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. Does this change the responses in the graphs too? And where exactly is the insert option, do you meant the "View in Sheets" button?

Comment: The answer assumed that you already had a form responses spreadsheet. Edited the answer. The summaries shown in the form at **Responses > Summary** will not change, but you can create your own charts in the spreadsheet with **Insert > Chart**.